# Do multiple indexes get used in queries with subqueries?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, subquery

My current query is a full text search, on a particular user's records. For this table, I have a FULLTEXT index over compColumn and a bTree over userID.

```
SELECT K.* FROM k_table AS K WHERE K.userID=2 AND (MATCH (K.compColumn) AGAINST ('+gatsby' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

From what I can tell, only one index gets used, and the WHOLE table is searched for the fulltext result, as opposed to just doing a fulltext search over user 2's records.

I was wondering how to set the above up having the user ID as a subquery, from which the fulltext search is then made, and if that would use the two indexes?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The MySQL documentation has a detailed explanation of how indexes are used.

Answer (score 0):

To make sub queries you put a query where you would logically put a table:

```
SELECT
  k2.*
FROM
  (SELECT 
    K.* 
  FROM 
    k_table AS K 
  WHERE K.userID=2) k2
WHERE
  MATCH (K2.compColumn) AGAINST ('+gatsby' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I don't think this will use the full text index. The result of a subquery isn't indexed.

Comment: Thanks for that, but Barmar is right - #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: You can add USE INDEX inside the subquery, however I recommend avoid the subquery.